# Screen Command challenges within Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I am using some Bash Script mixed with Monit to manage some dedicated gaming servers on my box. Everything works find apart form accessing the screen to shutdown the server with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -S l4d22 -p 0 -X stuff "quit\n"
```

When watching the screen as this is executed - "quit" is entered as an input and the cursor drops to the next line like return/enter has been pressed but it's although Enter isn't pressed...

If I access the screen manually and do this the server shutsdown gracefully as it should. Sorry it this is really dumb I am a little new to all this and just can't work this one out!

Many Thanks in Advance...

I've tried manually accessing the screen and testing the same command which works correctly

Comment: Try changing `\n` to `\r`.

Comment: Oh wow this place is clearly awesome, not sure why I've not been here before... Thank you so much @Barmar, that worked like a charm. I'm really grateful for such a quick reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuffing into a program that reads from the terminal in raw mode, you need to send a literal carriage return character. So change it to

```
screen -S l4d22 -p 0 -X stuff "quit\r"
```